# Downloading offline cache of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, visual-studio-2019

I want to be able to intall VS 2019 on multiple computers, it seems the only way available is by using the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#use-the-command-line-to-create-a-local-cache), I want to download these workloads (at minimum, and the developer will modify if needed):

> ASP.NET and web development
>
> .NET desktop development
>
> Mobile development with .NET
>
> .NET Core cross-platform development

but the CLI arguments for those workloads are not available in the previous link, then I have to download the complete workloads and components, which is very big in size. so I need the command to use for downloading those workloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of workload IDs is available from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2019).  You can use these as indicated in the examples on the page you listed.  For example you probably want a command like this (split into multiple lines for readability):

```
vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout 
  --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb 
  --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop 
  --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat
  --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools
  --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

If there are other components you want to include that are not part of the workloads, you can use the `--add` flag with any component ID listed from my link above - it's not limited to workloads.

If you want to trim down the size of the downloaded layout, you can change the `--includeOptional` to `--includeRecommended` or just leave it out entirely if you only want the bare bones workloads.  If you really want to optimize for download size, skip the workloads and just select the components you need.